# 'Node' conundrum

Tags: modeling, animation, workflow

**Before I begin here, I'm not talking about Node Editor nodes: I understand those just fine.**

I want to make an animation. Nothing too fancy - something like this:

[image: (Something very similar to this would be nice)]
In which the dots move around, the lines / connections with them.

However, my conundrum is that, *unlike* this, I would like the connections to be capped at a certain length. I can't really explain this, so here is another image.

[image]

So that dotted line would not be displayed. Anyway, my question is, how would I go about this? Freestyle? Shape keys? A lot of toggling that little eye on and off? Node or code wranglin'?

Comment: You can use [Sverchok](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/28792/3710). Not an expert, but I'm sure it provides an option to omit edges *longer than x*.

Comment: Seems like something that wouldnt be too difficult to script up. Find all node objects in a scene, get distances between them and draw cylinders between ones that are within a certain range. Do a move (random or organized) and repeat.

Comment: The title of this question won't be useful to others, but something like "automatically generating edges (with maximum length) between an animated set of Vertices" , might.

Comment: There is also similar question:
http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63091/how-to-animate-random-turbulence-on-a-mesh-surface/63552#63552

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [Sverchok](http://nortikin.github.io/sverchok/) or [Animation Nodes](https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes), if you are comfortable with Nodes (and don't want to write any Python). Because I am a developer of Sverchok I'll show how you might approach it using using that add-on.

#### Sverchok

*Generating the meandering vertices* is what looks most complicated here, but it's sampling points on a perlin-like 3d noise system. How you generate the position of your 3d points is up to you; could be read from a text file with xyz position per frame.

*Making Edges* is done with a single Node (*KDTree Closest Edges*) which makes K-Dimensional Tree of the incoming vertices and spits out the possible edges given the configuration parameters

- min distance
- max distance
- max num edges per vert
- skip first n edges per vert

[image]

[image]

That gets the basic concept going, then it's a matter of choice how to represent the Circles (verts) and Lines (probably flat shaded Curve Objects (straight) with thickness).

Then after experimenting with the meandering algorithm and min/max edge length, you'd add a few Viewer Nodes (BmeshViewer and Curve Viewer)

[image]

[image]

It can be animated by keyframing the left most Float node labelled *Driver Value*.