# Create point cloud with geo nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

Is there a convenient way to create this with geometry nodes?

[image]

Bonus: make it rotate and the individual points move a little bit do make it look more dynamic?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28789/create-plexus-plugin-like-effect https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63091/how-to-animate-random-turbulence-on-a-mesh-surface https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/248064/how-could-i-get-the-distance-of-a-point-to-its-nearest-point

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the node graph that I've found (version 3.4):

[image]

It connects random generated points that's close to each other, by distance threshold

[image]

Adding 4D noise texture with time offset by W makes it vibrate:

[image]

[image]

Comment: That looks promising. The Points node is only available in 3.4 dev, not in 3.2 I guess? Or is there an equivalent?